# Vapor pass data from postgres to a leaf template

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor

I'm new to Vapor,

I try to pass data from *postgres* to *leaf*.

In the **routes.swift** I have the function to render the leaf template:

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.get("all") { req -> EventloopFuture<View> in
        let todos = Todo.query(on: req.db).all()

        let context = TodoContext(todos: todos)

        return req.view.render("index", context)
    }
}
```

But I get an Error from the context line, it says *Cannot convert value of type 'EventLoopFuture<[Todo]>' to expected argument type '[Todo]'.*

How do I convert a EventLoopFuture<[Todo]> to '[Todo]' so I can use it in the context?
I try the map function after query .all(), but after this its still a EventLoopFuture<[Todo]>.

**The TodoContext:**

```
struct TodoContext: Content {
    let todos: [Todos]
}
```

**The Todo Model:**

```
final class Todo: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "todo"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "todo")
    var todo: String

    @Field(key: "complete")
    var complete: Bool

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, todo: string, complete: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.todo = todo
        self.complete = complete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you need to handle the future but you should use `flatMap` since the render call returns a future. So your code should look like:

```swift
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.get("all") { req -> EventloopFuture<View> in
        return Todo.query(on: req.db).all().flatMap { todos in
          let context = TodoContext(todos: todos)
          return req.view.render("index", context)
      }
    }
}
```